# Uploading a file to Elastic Beanstalk - will it be available on multiple instances?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudfront

I am going to be deploying a website to an EB instance soon. From what I've seen, this may result in multiple EC2 instances being created depending on how it needs to scale. I will be using CloudFront for static resources using origin pull, i.e. the image paths point to the CloudFront URL and CF then grabs the images from my server if it doesn't already have it cached.

My problem is what happens if a member updates their profile image and the site is running on 3 EC2 instances? The file is uploaded to the EC2 instance BUT will CF know which instance to check if it requests the file for the pull?

I suppose it could also be asked as this: if I have a website running on 3 EC2 instances and somebody uploads a file, will that file immediately be available on all instances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it will not. There is no shared storage by default.

If you'd like that, one idea would be to crate a separate file server and upload the files to a shared network filesystem.

If you can, it would probably be more scalable and secure to upload the files to S3 instead.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Amazon Elastic File System](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/) configured with your Elastic Beanstalk application should mean this is now possible.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/services-efs.html for some example configuration.